# Best CSS and JS Minifer for ASP.net Web Forms

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, bundle, minify

Criteria

- Work with ASP.Net MVC
- Support dotLess
- Generate very small QS param
- Support CSS and JS Both
- Support for development Mode and Production Mode
- Support Minification, bundling
- Support provider of the minification (Ajax Minifier, Yahoo UI) etc.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want [SquishIt](http://www.codethinked.com/squishit-the-friendly-aspnet-javascript-and-css-squisher). Don't know if it supports bundling.

Another Option: Create a T4 Template that uses the Microsoft Ajax Minifier (the AjaxMin.dll can be loaded into the AppDomain) and does the bundling.